# Launch application from the touchbar

Tags: macos, touch-bar

Is it possible to add an icon on the touchbar that would launch a custom application (to the right section that is always shown)? I want to add iterm2.

Answer (score 5):

Beside BTT, there is some free option that let you customize your Touch Bar as you like (with the customize widget they provide) and can make iterm2 appear thanks to the dock widget : [Pock](https://pock.dev/) & [EnergyBar](https://github.com/billziss-gh/EnergyBar)

[TouchSwitcher](https://hazeover.com/touchswitcher.html)  & [Rocket](http://julianthayn.com/rocket) are also a good call as they are only about quick launching an app.

There is also [My TouchBar My Rules](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR?ref=producthunt) who claims to be just like BTT, but free ! However it's looks like it's not very user friendly (but never had the chance to try it so far)

Comment: I tried all the apps, they all replace the application touch bar section and none of them provide the ability to control the system touch bar section (the right one). So I either sacrifice the space for the app, either a should do an additional action to trigger the docking menu and then the app. I understand there's no other way around

Answer (score 3):

Apple provides some simple modifications for the TouchBar — go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard and click the 'Customize Touch Bar...' button to see the available options — but none of them will accomplish what you want.  You can get [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) which will allow you to create custom touch bar items, but it is not a free app, and not (so far as I know) available in the App Store.

To set up a touch bar item that opens an application using BetterTouchTool,:

- Download, install, and then Open BetterTouchTool
- Select All Apps on the left, and select Touch Bar from the pull down menu at the top
- Click the '+' button to add a button/widget
- From the Select Trigger popover that appears, choose Touch Bar Button
- Give the button an icon and/or title, then click the '+' button to add an action
- Click the button labeled 'no action' to open the popover, then scroll down and open the 'controlling other apps section
- Choose 'Launch Application/...' and select the application you want to open

You should now have a touch bar item in the control item area that will open the app in question.

It may be possible to work something out with scripting for free; I'll look into it.

Comment: If you can add specific instructions for how to achieve this using BTT, I think that would be helpful!

Comment: @JBallin — I suppose I can download it and figure it out... 

Comment: I suppose, I was envisioning just researching how to do it. Whatever works.

Comment: Eh, the docs are lousy, and if I'm asking someone else to install it, I ought to install it myself. Just seems right...