# Get page number from Metadata instead of Index

Tags: applescript, pdf, metadata

In Applescript, we can get the index number of the current page we are viewing in `Skim` with the following code:

```
tell application "Skim"
    activate
    set theDoc to front document
    get index for current page of theDoc
end tell
```

Is there a way to access the *metadata* page number instead of the regular page index?

[image: metadata vs index]

---

## Assessibility Inspector Results

Accessibility Inspector just indicates that it is a text field. (Page number has been changed to 1098)

[image: inspector results]

---

## Another way to access the text field

With the following code, in which `{350, 55}` is the position where the text field is located on my screen,

```
tell application "System Events" to click at {350, 55}
```

I've found out that the text field can be accessed with:

```
text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window "程元敏 - 2013 - 尚書學史.pdf (page 1150 of 1696)" of application process "Skim" of application "System Events"
```

Hence, the following attempt to get its value.

```
tell application "Skim"
    activate
    set theDoc to front document
    get value of text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of theDoc
end tell
```

The above script resulted in this syntax error:

> Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”.

---

## Questions:

Besides telling me how to access the text field with code, I would also like to know why Accessibility Inspector failed to indicate any information about the text field?

Is there a way to *directly* access the metadata in of a pdf document with applescript?

Why do we have to embed `tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Skim"` within `tell application "Skim"` for the code to work?

Comment: Hi @sati ! Try accessibility inspector app and see if it is readable property

Comment: The text field can be accessed by `text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window "程元敏 - 2013 - 尚書學史.pdf (page 1150 of 1696)" of application process "Skim" of application "System Events"`

Comment: How about: `tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Skim" to get value of text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1`

Comment: It worked. But can `window 1` be accessed through `theDoc`? The window might not be active all the time.

Comment: Picking from @user3439894 `set appName to (name of every application process whose frontmost is true and visible is true) as string` answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381473/313842

Comment: @sati, do you know for sure that the page number is stored as metadata somewhere, and what do you actually mean by metadata?  Where do you believe this information is stored?  PDF documents **do**, indeed, have metadata stored in the file itself that contains information about the author, the document title, the year of publication, etc. These are all associated to the document, however, and I've not seen metadata that pertains to individual pages.  But if you know where it gets pulled from, that would be vital.

Comment: @CJK the way to access the metadata page number of a pdf file is given over [here](https://superuser.com/q/232553/775119).

Comment: Thank you for that. I never knew. But now I do, I know how you can access it and even edit it for a page with any given `index`.i can also answer the rest of your questions. Bear with me, and I'll compose an answer over the weekend and test that it works the way I think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an AppleScript that declares a handler to obtain a list of pages from a PDF document, to which you supply the file path.  When the handler is called, if the file path is valid, it should return an AppleScript `list` that contains the page label of every page, ordered by page index.  However, bear in mind that PDF pages are indexed from zero, while AppleScript `lists` are indexed from one.  Therefore, `item n` from the returned list gives you the page label for the page at index `n - 1`.

```
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "PDFKit"
use scripting additions

property this : a reference to the current application
property PDFDocument : a reference to PDFDocument of this

on PDFPagesInDocument at filepath
        local filepath

        try -- test file exists
                set fileURL to filepath as text ¬
                        as {alias, POSIX file} ¬
                        as «class fsrf»
        on error
                return false
        end try

        script pages
                property list : {}
        end script

        tell PDFDocument to tell alloc()
                initWithURL_(fileURL)
                repeat with i from 0 to pageCount() - 1
                        tell pageAtIndex_(i) to set the end of the ¬
                                list of pages to its label() as text
                end repeat
        end tell

        return the list of pages
end PDFPagesInDocument
```

After pasting the above code into the top of your own script, you could then use it like this:

```
choose file of type "com.adobe.pdf" with prompt "Select PDF File"
set PDFpath to the result

PDFPagesInDocument at PDFpath
```

This would allow the user to select a PDF file themselves whenever the script runs.  However, you can specify your own, hard-coded file path, as I do here:

```
PDFPagesInDocument at "/Users/CK/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/Sun Tzu - The Art of War trans Giles Pax Librorum 2009.pdf"
set pageList to the result

--> {"Cover", "i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v", "vi", "vii", "viii", "1", "2", "3", ¬
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", ¬
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", ¬
    "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", ¬
    "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", ¬
    "53", "54", "55", "56"}
```

As you can see, this particular PDF copy of Sun Tzu's *The Art of War* has 65 pages, where the page that a reader traditionally thinks of as being page 1, i.e. the first page one would flick to in order to begin reading a book's narrative, is the tenth page in the PDF file.

---

#### Other Questions:

> Is there a way to access the metadata page number instead of the regular page index?

Solution above.

> I would also like to know why Accessibility Inspector failed to indicate any information about the text field?

The software developer who codes an application gets to choose what information gets exposed for accessibility hooks.  There are guidelines that Apple lays out for developers to follow, and thankfully, most are conscientious and make sure their software reports information about the main UI elements, which, at a minimum, is meant to include the elements' name, description, object class, its purpose (or role), its position in the hierarchy, and a few other basic bits.

Besides being nice for those who script the UI to death, they actually serve a greater purpose, in aiding users with special needs to be able to interface with software that they otherwise wouldn't be able to use (for example, a blind person cannot *see* the value displayed for a page index, but voice over software would use accessibility hooks to retrieve the information and read it aloud to the user...provided the information has been exposed).

It appears *Skim* developers are just lazy or don't wish blind people to be using their software.

> I've found out that the text field can be accessed with:
>
> ```
> text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window "程元敏 - 2013 - 尚書學史.pdf (page 1150 of 1696)" of application process "Skim" of application "System Events"
> ```
>
> Hence, the following attempt to get its value:
>
> ```
> tell application "Skim"
>     activate
>     set theDoc to front document
>     get value of text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of theDoc
> end tell
> ```
>
> The above script resulted in this syntax error:
>
> ```
> Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”
> ```

The information you gleaned from the first snippet are class objects that all belong to the application *`System Events`*.  So when you then try to get application *`Skim`* to reference these objects, it can't: it's never heard of a `text field`.  It does, however, recognise `text` as the name of a class object (the class of all AppleScript strings), and then tentatively assumes that `field` is an identifier for a variable that it will need to look up and read the value from.  That's where it would ordinarily then complain that you never declared a variable with that identifier, but the word `"Page"` that immediately follows is a bigger concern, as this makes no sense to it in any context.

That's when the compiler categorises this as being a syntax error, reports the double quote as the definitively-illegal character that makes the entire expression impossible to evaluate.

That said, even if it wasn't a syntactical error, it would have led to a runtime error because your reference stops at `toolbar 1`, having completely omitted the parent object of `toolbar 1`, which is `window "程元敏 - 2013 - 尚書學史.pdf (page 1150 of 1696)"` (which you could also refer to as `window 1` for convenience), and ***its*** parent object, which is `process "Skim"`, and ***its*** parent object, which is `application "System Events"`.

What you needed to do is to take the snippet you were given, and use that with one tiny adjustment: the topmost object--which is the one at the *end* of the reference--is always going to be an `application` object, which in this case is *"System Events"*.  This is the object that owns all of the other objects that the reference contains, and is therefore the thing you need to be `tell`-ing:

```
tell application "System Events"
    value of text field "Page" of ¬
        group 2 of toolbar 1 of ¬
        window 1 of process "Skim"
end tell
```

However, do not--as you have done--put your `tell application "System Events"` block *inside* a `tell application "Skim"` block.  Although you don't see it, AppleScript bitches about this, generates an error (quietly), figures out what you do mean, then thankfully gets on with it.  But it slows things down, which is the best case scenario, but in other situations, it can cause overlapping object classes or terminology to clash.  If you're lucky, it'll just cause the script to terminate in a runtime error.  If you're unlucky, things get overwritten and data gets lost.

Unless there's a specific reason to, and you know precisely what you're doing when doing it, **don't ever** put one application `tell` block (or clause) inside another.  Generally speaking, since most languages only carry out one operation at a time anyway (this isn't true, but pretend it is, because it is for AppleScript), you will only ever be getting AppleScript to talk to one application at any particularly point in your script, so try and make sure that this is the case when you review what you've written.

Comment: Updated answer, which is now complete.  Answered all questions from OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code that worked:

```
tell application "Skim"
    activate
    set theDoc to front document
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Skim"
        set metaPage to (get value of text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1)
    end tell
end tell
```

Hope some of you could answer my other questions indicated above.

---

Taking the advice from @CJK's answer above, I have amended my code as follows:

```
tell application "Skim"
    activate
    set theDoc to front document
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Skim"
     set metaPage to (get value of text field "Page" of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1)
end tell
```